# Sears Craftsman Table Saw Model Number

Tags: table-saw

I purchased a Sears Craftsman Tablesaw from Craigslist, and I am looking for the proper model number for the unit in order to grab the proper replacement parts for it as necessary.  On the sticker at the unit, it says:

```
10-IN. PREMIUM HYBRID TABLE SAW
5/8" BLAD ARBOR, 3450 RPM
3 5/16" DEPTH OF CUT AT 90D
2 1/4" DEPTH OF CUT AT 45D
1 3/4 HP CONTINUOUS DUTY
MODEL NO: `320.221161`
```

However, the manual provided by the seller notes:

```
MODEL NO: `351.221161`
```

The manual appears that the "351" has a gray background behind the text, like it was updated.  The seller also wrote a "0" at the end of the number in pen making it `351.2211610`

For somebody pretty new to woodworking this is a bit confusing!  I have found [model 22116 on Sears](http://www.searsoutlet.com/1-3-4-HP-Premium-Hybrid-10-Table-Saw-22116-/d/product_details.jsp?pid=32628) currently, and this looks visually identical to my unit.

Does anyone know what the proper model number to use is, in order to obtain the proper digital manual and for parts ordering?  Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

> Does anyone know what the proper model number to use is, in order to obtain the proper digital manual and for parts ordering?

I would trust the model number on the saw itself more than the manual.  Who knows if it's even the right manual that the seller gave you?  Heck, the wrong manual could have even been packed with the table saw from the manufacturer, but the model stickers on the unit are usually correct.

If you're really unsure, you can always take a picture of the model sticker on the saw and bring it and the manual to a Sears to ask someone there what parts to order.

I'm guessing that a lot of their parts are interchangeable between saw models, so it may not matter too much.

Comment: Yup, I was going to suggest taking pictures and model numbers to Sears. Depending on your local Sears, you may find varying levels of helpfulness with the floor sales guys, but someone will help you out.